# Using syntax to trigger the calling of all objects that implement Dispose method

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, using-statement

Is it possible to use **using** syntax to trigger all objects that implement
IDisposable interface call the corresponding Dispose() method?

For example, if the objects of ObjectOne and ObjectTwo exist in the *section of interest*, can we make it the way so that the Dispose() method of both objects will be called automatically. As the example shown, I knew how to do it for one Class type, but I don't know how to do this kind of trick for more than one Class type. Because the following syntax is not allowed in C#.

// This is not a valid C# statement

```
using( ObjectOne one = new ObjectOne();
       OjbectTwo two = new ObjectTwo() )
{
   ...  

  // hopefully, the Dispose methods of both **one** and **two** will be called.
}
```

A concrete example to illustrate how to trigger the auto-calling Dispose method for just one class type.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ObjectOne : IDisposable
    {
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }

        public ObjectOne() : this("Empty") { }
        public ObjectOne(string objName) 
        {
            ObjectName = objName;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjectOne.Dispose " + ObjectName);
        }
    }

    class ObjectTwo : IDisposable
    {
        public string ObjectTwoName { get; set; }

        public ObjectTwo() { }
        public ObjectTwo(string objName)
        {
            ObjectTwoName = objName;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjectTwo.Dispose " + ObjectTwoName);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("before");

            // make sure that the Dispose method of object one1 and one2 is called
            using (ObjectOne one1 = new ObjectOne(),
                             one2 = new ObjectOne()
                   )
            {
                // section of interest
                Console.WriteLine("middle");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("after");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i have different type of objects in a C# *using* block ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092167/can-i-have-different-type-of-objects-in-a-c-using-block)

Comment: @It seems that the only solution is to concatenate using statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest using statements:

```
using( ObjectOne one = new ObjectOne())
   using( OjbectTwo two = new ObjectTwo() )
   {
      ...  

     // hopefully, the Dispose methods of both **one** and **two** will be called.
   }
```

**EDIT:** the only other way would be to implement a custom list of IDisposables:

```
public class DisposableList : List<IDisposable>, IDisposable
{
   //this is all you need if you will ONLY use it in a using statement or explicitly call Dispose;
   //there is a more developed pattern that performs disposal automatically on finalization.
   public void Dispose()
   {
      foreach(var disposable in this)
         disposable.Dispose();
   }
}

...

using(var disposables = new DisposableList{new ObjectOne(), new ObjectTwo()})
{
   //unfortunately, you must now cast the items back to their types 
   //in order to use them as anything but IDisposables.
   var objectOne = (ObjectOne)disposables[0];
   var objectTwo = (ObjectTwo)disposables[1];

   ...
}
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but I am looking for a possible alternative solution. My concern is that if I have 10 such objects, I have to embedded the using 10 times.

Comment: Unless you want to place all of the objects into a List<IDisposable> and then loop over each and call .Dispose() you won't get around it.

Answer (score 4):

```
using (ObjectOne one1 = new ObjectOne())                       
using (ObjectTwo one2 = new ObjectTwo())                      
{                 
   // !!!section of interest!!!                 
   Console.WriteLine("middle");             
}
```

This will call dispose on both objects after the code block.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the question I asked some time back

[Can i have different type of objects in a C# *using* block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092167/can-i-have-different-type-of-objects-in-a-c-using-block)

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f), 
           font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

The above is how you handle multiple objects of **same** type. As answered in the above question, you can also handle multiple objects of **different** types as well.

Comment: @I have posted this solution in the example. Here my focus is the second part.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Multiple objects can be used with a
>   using statement, but they must be
>   declared inside the using statement,
>   as in the following example:

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f),
            font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

---

**Edit:** After testing your code, I see the problem. You can't do it with multiple types. So what about something like this:

```
using (ObjectOne one1 = new ObjectOne())
using (ObjectTwo one2 = new ObjectTwo()) {
    // !!!section of interest!!!
    Console.WriteLine("middle");
}
```

This essentially nests one using in the other.

Note: In my console this outputs:

```
before
middle
ObjectTwo.Dispose 
ObjectOne.Dispose Empty
after
```

Comment: @Please take a look my posted example, I have shown how to do this in the code.

Comment: as other people mentioned above, I may not have an alternative way to do this except by using embedded "using" statement. Hopefully, in the near future, C#? may introduce a better solution. -- thank you

Comment: @q0987: This is essentially the same as if you were allowed use different types within the using. What would you want more than this?